# Resize image on url with php

Tags: php, image, resize

I have an image stored in a web server.For eg  https://victorthemes.com/themes/glazov/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/p-sidebar-two.jpg

Now I want to resize that image with php.

I found this code, but its too old and its not working with php 7.2

```
<?php
    $remote_file = 'https://victorthemes.com/themes/glazov/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/p-sidebar-two.jpg';
    $new_width = 342;
    $new_height = 268;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($remote_file);
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file);        
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
    imagejpeg($image_p, NULL, 100);
    imagedestroy($image_p);
?>
```

Comment: please add the errors your are getting to the question. one thing that you need to adapt for PHP 7 is the list operator. the order has changed, but swapping $weight and $height should do the trick. see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: PHP manual has an example that seems very similar http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php what error you getting exactly? @ErikKalkoken the order has only changed for assignment to arrays, so should work the same in this case on both versions